# Can we disable tabs in IE8?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

IE7 allows to disable tabs to retain the single window working functionality as in IE6. Can we do the same in IE8? Can we disable tabbed browsing in IE8?

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to disable tabs?

Comment: Workplace restrictions, I imagine. Not having tabs is awful, though, Anand! Is there really no better way?

Comment: Hi, needed to do so because our team has develop some scripts in QTP. This scripts were developed using IE6. Now if we need to run the same in IE8 because of the tabbed browsing, it some-how failed and that's why we needed to disable this. Though disabling the tabs is not a good solution, but till we update all our scripts in such a way that it works in tabbed browsing mode, this is one of the solution to get our existing scripts work.

Please suggest if other alternatives are available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to disable tabs in IE8:

- go to Tools > Internet Options
- click on the Settings button from the Tabs section
- uncheck "Enable Tabbed Browsing"
- click "OK" twice to close the two dialogs
- restart IE

Comment: That answer is for windows 7 , no you can't disable tabs in windows 8. Enable or disable is not in internet tools go there and see.