# Hide tabs for single tab in IE8

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

I've serached the options menus, and read [this question](https://superuser.com/q/56466/94931) about disabling tabbed browsing, but that's not what I want to do.

When there is only 1 tab open in IE8, it still shows as a tab, instead of just using the whole window. Is there a way to disable this, such that the tabs at the top only appear when there are multiple tabs open?

Screenshot of the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to disable this.